# Uninstall WiX bootstrapper after I uninstall my msi

Tags: wix, exe, shortcut, uninstallation, bootstrapper

I have one WiX setup project which produces my application's msi installer and I have also setup the uninstall shortcut feature for the application. In addition, I have a WiX bootstrapper project which detects and install .NET and VC++ during installation on the user's computer.
The bootstrapper works fine and can detect and install .net and vc++, and also install my application.

However, the issue I am facing is that when I uninstall my application using the shortcut in the Program Menu folder, it can successfully uninstall my application but there still is an entry of the bootstrapper in the "**Add and Remove Programs(ARP)**". I have to manually uninstall it by going on to the ARP.

My question is: How do I uninstall the bootstrapper exe without having to go to the ARP everytime? My msi uninstalls fine from the shortcut but I do not know how I can uninstall the exe with a shortcut.

This is how my bootstrapper bundle looks like:

```
    <Chain>
        <!-- NetFx46Web: Checks whether .NET 4.6 is installed in user comp. If not, install it via a web installer -->
        <PackageGroupRef Id="NetFx46Web"/>

        <!-- VC++ 2013 install -->
        <PackageGroupRef Id="vcredist2013_x86"/>

        <!-- Reference the setup msi installer -->
        <MsiPackage Id="my_msi" SourceFile="$(var.InstallProj.TargetPath)" DisplayInternalUI="yes" />
    </Chain>
```

Comment: Going to ARP is a Windows standard. Having a shortcut to an uninstaller is against the standard. After all, that's why a bootstrapper lists itself there. So, one alternative is to have no shortcut. (Obviously, this isn't an answer to your question.)

Comment: Yes it is not an answer to my question. I have no issues with my application going to the ARP. The problem is that the uninstall shortcut is created by the msi installer, not the bootstrapper. Is there any way to uninstall via the bootstrapper?

Comment: Maybe this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19833338/2226988) if you want to build your own bootstrapper application.